# Issue in Appium java Configuration for Android on Windows 7 environment

Tags: java, android, appium

I am new to `appium` and android automation
However from different blogs I have been able to start with the configuration of `Appium` for Android Automation on W7 environment using Java
But, somehow my `TestNG` java script doesn't launch the `.apk` file in the android emulator
Below are the last few lines of the logs that the `appium` server is showing:-

> debug: Appium request initiated at /wd/hub/session/e4d57ac4-83df-448f-a825-dc985
>   4de0ed6
>   info: Shutting down appium session...
>   info: [ADB] Pressing the HOME button
>   info: Sent shutdown command, waiting for ADB to stop...
>   info: Stopping logcat capture
>   warn: Android did not shut down fast enough, calling it gone
>   info: [ADB] Not uninstalling app since server not started with --full-reset
>   info: Clearing out appium devices
>   info: Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":null,"sessionId":"e
>   4d57ac4-83df-448f-a825-dc9854de0ed6"}
>   DELETE /wd/hub/session/e4d57ac4-83df-448f-a825-dc9854de0ed6 200 7533ms - 89

Below is my java code:-

```
           @BeforeMethod

           public void setup() {

           File appDir = new File("E:/Softwares/AppToBeTested");

           File app = new File(appDir, "ContactManager.apk");

           DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

           capabilities.setCapability("device","Android");

           capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");

           capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "4.2.2");

           capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, "WINDOWS");


          // capabilities.setCapability("app-package","com.deo.mobile1");
          capabilities.setCapability("app-package","com.example.android.contactmanager");

            //Here we mention the activity name, which is invoked initially as app's first page.

         // capabilities.setCapability("app-activity",".StartupActivity");
         capabilities.setCapability("app-activity",".ContactManager");

         //capabilities.setCapability("app-wait-activity","LoginActivity,NewAccountActivity");

         capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());

         try {
   driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
         } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
        }

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  


        }

       @Test

       public void loginTest() throws Exception 
       {
       System.out.println("Hello");

       }

       @AfterMethod

       public void tearDown() 
       {

           driver.quit();

       }
```

Note:-
I can see the android emulator navigating to the home screen but nothing happens after that
I already have ContactManager.apk installed in the emulator

Comment: Hi, The above issue is now solved. But, now I am facing another issue...I  get following error :-

org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: A session is either terminated or not started (Original error: Activity used to start app doesn't exist! Make sure it exists) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: You should start appium server first, also if session ternimated with above message. close all instance of Adb rerun appium server and the run test scripts. Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

If you get SessionNotFoundException it seems you didn't set up your session correctly. How did you start Appium?

I'm using Windows 7 myself and I wrote me a little batch script to launch Appium:

```
@ECHO OFF

cd C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium

node server.js --app "<path-to-your-project>\bin\AppName.apk"
```

I installed Appium via npm, if you downloaded the Windows package from their page, server.js should be located somewhere in the "Program files" folder with the Appium content.

After you started appium like this, you should be able to retrieve that session and execute commands.

Let me know if this helped you.